# MySQL rank calculation is failing, variable always null

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to maintain the stored rank index of each row in a MySQL table based on the value of a rating column in the same row. I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function?lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553308/mysql-help-optimize-update-query-that-sets-rank-according-to-order-of-another-c) but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM `MyTable` T
JOIN
(
    SELECT `id`, @rownum=@rownum+1 AS `rank_calculated`
    FROM `MyTable`, (SELECT @rownum=0) AS `inline_trick`
    ORDER BY `rating`
) R
ON R.`id` = T.`id`
```

This selects all rows in `MyTable` but the `rank_calculated` column is always null. Can anyone tell me why?

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.34, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `:=`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `MyTable` T JOIN
     (SELECT `id`, @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS `rank_calculated`
      FROM `MyTable`, (SELECT @rownum:=0) AS `inline_trick`
      ORDER BY `rating`
    ) R
    ON R.`id` = T.`id`;
```

EDIT:

Just to be clear, within a `select` statement `=` refers to boolean comparison, not assignment.  You need `:=` for an assignment.  You can read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/assignment-operators.html).